# Selecting articles category based on probability of already read categories

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to show user articles based on his user activity.

My user activity table has 3 columns ID,Category,Name
So basically once a user read/click article these "three" fields updates based on which category of article he selected

Now based on his user activity i would like to show 10 articles from articles table based on which category of article he selected most
for example

```
Category   # of articles read   
Sports           7
Weather          3
```

So the recommendation page should select 7 articles from sports category and 3 articles from weather category

Here is the code i have done so far

```
#Reading Articles from CSV
articles = pd.read_csv('articles.csv')

#User Activity Data
data = pd.read_csv('atc.csv',nrows=2000)

data1=data.rename(columns={'Category ':'Category'})
user_ac = data1[data1.Name=="Roxana"]

# number of articles read by 'Roxana' for each category
calc = user_ac.groupby('Category').count()['ID ']


#Sorting
sorted = calc.sort_values(ascending=False)

#Find probability for each category
b = user_ac.groupby('Category').count().div(len(user_ac))['ID ']
b=b.sort_values(ascending=False)

n_recommendation = 10
```

How can i achieve this using pandas ?

GDRIVE LINK OF USER ACTIVITY 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d6rG0TE3dGYuU41AfTwn5T7dyoDniElY/view?usp=sharing

GDRIVE LINK OF Articles Data
https://drive.google.com/file/d/15cK4p9vonmNNRZ_C5d26ULRivx6zSkrE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: [Provide a copy of the DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-do-i-provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-my-existing-dataframe)

Comment: Please see my edits , I have included dataframes.

Comment: Sorry i have uploaded wrong file , Now i have replaced with CSV File called Articles which have articles data

Comment: The question states, the recommender suggests 7 sport and 3 weather articles.  This doesn't correspond to the user `Roxana` in the code; she has read no weather related articles.  The code aggregates some data and calculates the ratio or Categories for the user.  Based upon the example, it's not possible to determine how you want to make a recommendation.

Comment: I didn't drill into your data but probably you can:
1) shuffle your article dataframe
2) add a new column, assign incremental number group by type
3) select row where (type == 'sport' and num < 7) &  (type == 'weather' and num < 3)

Comment: Building a recommendation engine is a very broad topic.  [Comprehensive Guide to build a Recommendation Engine from scratch (in Python)](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/06/comprehensive-guide-recommendation-engine-python/)

Comment: Basically I want to recommend  X user articles based on what percentage of article category he read , so if a user has read 70 % of sports articles he should be shown most of articles related to sports category